# How to define the base path for tests done with npm

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, npm, eslint

The web application I'm developing is a typical web app done with Angular as front-end technology and Java spring boot as backend.

[image: project directories structure]

As you can see in the above picture, I create another directory in the root folder named `filebeat-7.12-darwin-x86_64` that contains some `js` files.

When I try to run the javascript test with command `npm run webapp:test`, I receveid a lot of errors. I notice that as default configuration the `*.js`, `*.ts` files that **lint** try to analyze were look for in `filebeat-7.12-darwin-x86_64` folder too.

There is a way to specify for the command `npm run webapp:test` from which folder it has to start to test? I report just some lines of the log the command I mentioned produced.

```
> sample-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:test /Users/dummy/git/sample-app
> npm run test


> sample-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT pretest /Users/dummy/git/sample-app
> npm run lint


> sample-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT lint /Users/dummy/git/sample-app
> eslint . --ext .js,.ts


/Users/dummy/git/sample-app/filebeat-7.12.1-darwin-x86_64/module/barracuda/spamfirewall/config/liblogparser.js
     7:17   error    Require statement not part of import statement                                                              @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
     8:15   error    Require statement not part of import statement                                                              @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
    33:1    error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    40:18   error    'DeviceProcessor' is not defined                                                                            no-undef
    43:1    error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    54:13   error    Unsafe return of an any typed value                                                                         @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
    57:35   error    Unnecessary escape character: \-                                                                            no-useless-escape
    59:23   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
    61:20   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
    61:20   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
    61:20   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers                                       @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
    65:1    error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    70:21   error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    71:30   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
    72:16   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
    77:1    error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    77:10   warning  'process' is defined but never used                                                                         @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    83:5    error    Unsafe return of an any typed value                                                                         @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
    86:1    error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    89:5    error    Unsafe return of an any typed value                                                                         @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
    92:10   warning  'linear_select' is defined but never used                                                                   @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    98:13   error    Expected { after 'if' condition                                                                             curly
    98:37   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
   101:13   error    Expected { after 'if' condition                                                                             curly
   102:13   error    Expected { after 'if' condition                                                                             curly
   102:37   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
   109:30   error    Operands of '+' operation must either be both strings or both numbers. Consider using a template literal    @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
   127:5    warning  'strip_syslog_priority' is assigned a value but never used                                                  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
   128:21   error    Missing return type on function                                                                             @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
   133:19   error    Missing return type on function
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the --include parameter with the ng test. This option specifies the folders to run the tests. Please take a look: https://angular.io/cli/test#options

Or maybe exclude ts lint from the angular.json file:
In the lint section, you can add the path/to/folder

```
"exclude": ["**/filebeat-7.12.1-darwin-x86_64/**"]
```